# How to generate public and private key for API

Tags: php

I want the easy way in order to generate Public / Private key for API, i want a speed class without need of OPENSSL or Any server side installation or third party application.

I tried to look about a Bitcoin Public/Private system generation, but nothing found about it ... and then i tested:

```
require_once('PHPCoinAddress.php');


$coin = CoinAddress::bitcoin();          coin_info('Bitcoin', $coin);


//////////////////////////////////////////////
function coin_info($name,$coin) {

    print 'public (base58): ' . $coin['public'] . "<br>";
    print 'private (WIF)  : ' . $coin['private'] . "<br>";
}
```

But this take many times in order to return a result !

**Source from here:** https://github.com/zamgo/PHPCoinAddress

If u have any easy, speed, secure and unique pair generation solution will be welcome ! Thank's in advance.

Comment: Generating secure cryptographic keys is something that inherently takes time. You can't really get around that. You could always pre-compute some keypairs though and just generate more when you are about to run out though.

Comment: A question, what makes `PHPCoinAddress` less third party than `openssl`?

Comment: I need a class that generate any secure and unique keypair, but without using third party application installed ! just using PHP or any class that is supported on any server.

Comment: @MacLove Well that's going to be far slower than using a native C implementation like OpenSSL.

Comment: @Chris OpenSSL can't be installed on my server, it's for this i need a solution that don't require OpenSSL.

Comment: Okay, well anything that is implemented in plain PHP is almost certainly going to be slow, especially things that make heavy use of BC Math like PHPCoinAddress.

Comment: What about mCrypt ? and how to use it in order to generate unique and secure private and public key ?

Comment: Worth mentioning, PHPCoinAddress is known to generate insecure (predictable) private keys. You should not use any of the keys it generates.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but somebody may find interesting that maybe [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) is a solution for such an use case:

From the introduction:

> Compatibility
>
> phpseclib is designed to be ultra-compatible. It works on PHP4+ (PHP4,
>   assuming the use of PHP_Compat) and doesn't require any extensions.
>   For purposes of speed, mcrypt is used if it's available as is gmp or
>   bcmath (in that order), but they are not required. Interoperability
>
> phpseclib is designed to be fully interoperable with OpenSSL and other
>   standardized cryptography programs and protocols.